# TRIPLE DES ECB Encryption RUBY

Tags: c#, ruby, openssl, 3des, ecb

I have a sample code in .NET C# which I need to convert to RUBY.

```
 public static string Encrypt(string pstrText)
        {
            byte[] keyArray;
            byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pstrText);
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secKey));
                hashmd5.Clear();
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tdes.Key = keyArray;
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] resultArray =cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
            tdes.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
        }
```

I have tried using OPENSSL:CIPHER and got thus far -

```
def encrypt data
secret = "******************"
md5 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(secret)
des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new 'DES-EDE3'
des.encrypt
des.key = md5
update_value = des.update(data)
up_final = update_value + des.final
puts Base64.encode64(up_final).gsub(/\n/, "")
end
```

The results in C# and RUBY do not match. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you provide both common inputs and different outputs for both methods to help understand what is the expected behaviour?
From what I see in the code, PKCS7 is not configured in the Ruby version of your implementation, maybe try specifying padding.

Comment: Common Input - "Hello"
C# Output - "7dFl8i/7XvA="
Ruby Output - "yI4i1E49dAQ="

Comment: Hm, I get `"tTTahnSXXW8="` when running your code with `data = "Hello"` and `secret = "******************"`. Have you maybe used another secret? Also,  Ruby uses PKCS7 padding by default, so your issue should not be related to that.

Comment: Sorry, correction - Common Input - "Hello" C# Output - "w4yjgRJriP4=" Ruby Output - "tTTahnSXXW8=" . And I know that the C# output is correct.

Comment: Ok, I think all configuration looks right. So you will need to do some debugging.
I got curious in 
`Digest::MD5.hexdigest(secret)` (`"28306617aacbf026bf9a4e0783b50ff9"`)
vs.
`hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secKey))`
(Could you post this line's return value here?)

Comment: Ok, I got the C# value... `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(secret)` is `"28306617aacbf026bf9a4e0783b50ff9"` (which gives you `[50, 56, 51, 48, 54, 54, 49, 55, 97, 97, 99, 98, 102, 48, 50, 54, 98, 102, 57, 97, 52, 101, 48, 55, 56, 51, 98, 53, 48, 102, 102, 57]` when calling `.bytes.to_a`)
but
`hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secKey))` gives you `{ 40, 48, 102, 23, 170, 203, 240, 38, 191, 154, 78, 7, 131, 181, 15, 249 }`. That looks very different to me. It's probably worth digging deeper here.

Comment: You are correct about the RUBY Values, but the interesting thing is, doing a BitConverter.ToString on hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secKey)) gives me - "28-30-66-17-AA-CB-F0-26-BF-9A-4E-07-83-B5-0F-F9" which is same as given by Digest::MD5.hexdigest(secret) in RUBY

Comment: Hm, that's confusing. I'm afraid I won't be able to figure this out. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you.